# How to interpret this traceback for distributed training across CPU cores?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what my program is having issue with, but the traceback, to me, is not very clear. I am wondering if you can help me decipher where the problem probably is.

My goal is to use multiple CPU workers to run this code in parallel through torch's dataloader.

Below is what my logger has caught:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
                └ ModuleSpec(name='models.bert_glue.__main__', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000152721584C8...

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
         │     └ {'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'models.bert_glue', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.Source...
         └ <code object <module> at 0x0000015272160930, file "C:\BERTVision\code\torch\models\bert_glue\__main__.py", line 2>

> File "C:\BERTVision\code\torch\models\bert_glue\__main__.py", line 114, in <module>
    trainer.train()
    │       └ <function BertGLUETrainer.train at 0x0000015202805A68>
    └ <common.trainers.bert_glue_trainer.BertGLUETrainer object at 0x0000015204AB1088>

  File "C:\BERTVision\code\torch\common\trainers\bert_glue_trainer.py", line 160, in train
    self.train_epoch(train_dataloader)
    │    │           └ <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x0000015204AA50C8>
    │    └ <function BertGLUETrainer.train_epoch at 0x0000015202805B88>
    └ <common.trainers.bert_glue_trainer.BertGLUETrainer object at 0x0000015204AB1088>

  File "C:\BERTVision\code\torch\common\trainers\bert_glue_trainer.py", line 89, in train_epoch
    for step, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader, desc="Training")):
                                 │    └ <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x0000015204AA50C8>
                                 └ <class 'tqdm.asyncio.tqdm_asyncio'>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\site-packages\tqdm\asyncio.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.iterable_iterator = iter(iterable)
    │                             └ <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x0000015204AA50C8>
    └ Training:   0%|                                                                                                              ...

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 282, in __iter__
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
           │                              └ <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x0000015204AA50C8>
           └ <class 'torch.utils.data.dataloader._MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter'>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 728, in __init__
    w.start()
    │ └ <function BaseProcess.start at 0x0000015278307438>
    └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
    │    │        │    │      └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
    │    │        │    └ <staticmethod object at 0x0000015278301748>
    │    │        └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
    │    └ None
    └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           │                │                            └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
           │                └ <function DefaultContext.get_context at 0x00000152783135E8>
           └ <multiprocessing.context.DefaultContext object at 0x0000015278309A08>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           │     └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
           └ <class 'multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32.Popen'>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
    │         │    │            └ <_io.BufferedWriter name=5>
    │         │    └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
    │         └ <function dump at 0x0000015278304F78>
    └ <module 'multiprocessing.reduction' from 'C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Anaconda3\\envs\\my_ml\\lib\\multiprocessing\\reduction.py'>

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Anaconda3\envs\my_ml\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
    │              │     │              └ <Process(Process-1, initial daemon)>
    │              │     └ None
    │              └ <_io.BufferedWriter name=5>
    └ <class 'multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler'>

TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to pass an unserializable object between processes. To pass an object between processes in Python, it needs to be broken down into its bytes. You can test if an object will work by trying to pickle it. As a first remedy, don’t use iPython with Multiprocessing. That’s incredibly finicky.

Comment: Also pleas provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks I will try pickling my objects and seeing what the issue is -- I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlexNe, the issue is that the dataloader is not pickle-able given its location in the program.